# Access 2007 Macro Designer - Get and reuse parameter from user

Tags: ms-access, macros, ms-access-2007

I have a simple Access macro that opens two forms and filters them based on input from the user.

I used parameter queries to accomplish this, so my Where condition for both reports reads:

```
[PONumber]=[Enter PO Number]
```

As it currently stands, an input box pops up twice - once for each report. I was hoping that I could somehow re-use the value from the first input box.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would dissent from @HansUp's answer. Don't hardwire any criteria into your saved QueryDefs, nor into the recordsources of forms and reports. Instead, open the forms/reports with WHERE criteria chosen by opening an unbound form to collect the relevant criteria.